# In Mongoose can I create a virtual which populates and then filters the populated documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a model ItemModel and another model, ItemInstances.  Hopefully those names are self-explanatory.  I want to create a virtual in my Mongoose ItemSchema that will return the number of ItemInstances that are associated with that Item and that have a status of "In Stock".  So far, I've been able to populate the ItemInstances via a virtual property in the ItemSchema, as so:

```
ItemSchema.virtual('numberInStock', {
    ref: 'ItemInstance',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'item',
});
```

This successfully populates the associated ItemInstances (gives me an array).  This is the array that is returned:

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("619be4da2f47a46f785a473a"),
    item: new ObjectId("619be4d92f47a46f785a472c"),
    status: 'Damaged',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("619be4da2f47a46f785a473c"),
    item: new ObjectId("619be4d92f47a46f785a472c"),
    status: 'In Stock',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("619be4da2f47a46f785a473b"),
    item: new ObjectId("619be4d92f47a46f785a472c"),
    status: 'In Stock',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

I want the virtual itself to filter the ItemInstances that have a status of "In Stock", and then return the number of those.

I know that I could filter the results in a query, but that's not my intention.

Answer (score 1):

````js
    ItemSchema.virtual('numberInStock', {
        ref: 'ItemInstance',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'item',
        options: {
            match: {
                status: 'In Stock',
            },
        },
        count: true,
    });
    ```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I couldn't find this 'options' in Mongoose doc, but it works.. Thank you very much.